# moviepy not finding ImageMagick on win

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, moviepy

On a Anaconda3 4.1.1 distribution on Windows 7 64bit I installed moviepy 0.2.2.11 by using `pip install moviepy`. Now I want to test some examples with animated text which demands ImageMagick. So I downloaded and installed `ImageMagick-7.0.3-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe` but according to https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html on windows the path needs to be specified manually. If I understand correctly this has to be done before compilation. However as I used pip for installation I don't know how to tell moviepy the path.

Secondly it seems that there is no convert.exe. I can however use e.g. `magick convert image.png image.gif`. So is this version of ImageMagick compatible with moviepy at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing `convert.exe` indeed turned out to be the problem.
As mentioned in this [conversation](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29582) the windows installer has in fact an option to create legacy compments like the convert.exe.
Once I re-installed ImageMagick with the option ticked it worked right away. Apparently there is no need any more for fiddling with the config files during installation of moviepy on windows.
There is a tutorial on what steps to take to make moviepy work on windows including the installation of ImageMagick [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/568bvb/looking_for_tutorial_for_windows_setup_of_moviepy/). It does however not mention the option to install the legacy components.

Comment: ImageMagick 7 uses "magick.exe" not "convert.exe". If you have installed the legacy components, then magick convert should work.

Answer (score 5):

1. find your moviepy's catalog, then find the moviepy/config_defaults.py, open this file and add after the last line:

   ```
   IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick_VERSION\\convert.exe
   ```
2. if you have no convert.exe, maybe it is caused by your installation. When you install *ImageMagick*, you must tick the

   ```
   [Install legacy utilities.(e.g.convert]
   ```